# Unable to get Sale Transaction detail by calling PayPal REST APIs

Tags: java, rest, paypal

I'm in the middle of managing payments through PayPal REST APIs in my project using the Sandbox account. I'm able to make payments through the REST APIs, but I'm not able to get the Sale Transaction details by calling the REST API with the sale id and its throwing some exception. Given below its details,

```
Request : v1/payments/sale/{saleId}

Response: com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalRESTException: Error code : 500 with response : {"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","message":"An internal service error has occurred","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"7d4370359c9d9"}
at com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalRESTException.createFromHttpErrorException(PayPalRESTException.java:66)
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing a bug/outage from PayPal. Please contact [Merchant Technical Support](https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask/) with this issue. Be sure to include the `debug_id` from the error response.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have also contacted the Technical Support team with the debug_id, but no response from them till now.